# Visa starts a day after boarding time

Tags: visas, schengen

I have a flight from Delhi to Paris with a layover at Colombo.

The flight starts at 18:45 21st July to Colombo and then at 00:15 22nd July from Colombo to Paris.
My Schengen visa starts on 22nd July.

Will this be an issue while boarding at Delhi? My main flight to Paris is from Colombo which will board at 22nd July but the entry point Delhi starts at 21st July.

I have tried contacting Srilankan airlines with no response.

Has anyone faced something similar?

Answer (score 2):

What is important is that you enter the Schengen Area (pass through passport control) during your visa validity.

Whether you start your trip on the day or 5 days earlier is of no issue, they only care about when you enter the country/in this case Area.

You will have no issues in either Delhi or Colombo

From @Aganju

> Mostly true - but you cannot plan idle a day or even some hours before passport control or so. The plane landing time must be after visa start

Comment: Mostly true - but you cannot plan idle a day or even some hours before passport control or so. The plane landing time must be after visa start.